# HMS Map Kit - How to set camera zoom to current location?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit, huawei-location-kit

I would like to make the map auto-focus to the current location and I've obtained the location via Location Kit.

```
fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
```

Now, I was trying to set the latitude and longitude of the camera in `OnMapReady()` function, but how to retrieve them?

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(HuaweiMap huaweiMap) {
    float zoom = 12.0f;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(***mLat***, ***mLong***);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I really need your assistance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

There is a official [demo](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-ecommerce-demo) show how to realize this:

[use location kit to get the current location](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-ecommerce-demo/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/huawei/industrydemo/shopping/service/LocationService.java)

[use map kit to show current location point in map](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-ecommerce-demo/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/huawei/industrydemo/shopping/page/map/MapMarkerFrag.java)

---

You can try to use the function `moveCamera`  or `animateCamera` to make the map move to the location you want :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(HuaweiMap huaweiMap) {
    float zoom = 12.0f;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(***mLat***, ***mLong***);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
    huaweiMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);        
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But how can I get the lat and long of the current location?

Comment: hi @jxhau,i updated my answer,you can refer that.